# How to apply the algorithm concepts in a project application

Tags: algorithm, project

I want to apply the concepts I have studied in algorithm and artificial intelligent in my project. So can any one provide me a sample application example where did can I apply?
I have taken courses algorithm and AI. Some of the courses I had taken include

- Divide and conquer
- Dynamic programming
- Backtrack
- Greedy Algorithm
  ..Etc 
  My main question is I want to apply the concepts of these algorithm and others in my senior project. So can any body suggest me any application that involves these concepts
  Thank you

Comment: Do you want to write a "project application" just to apply all those algorithms? Maybe write a demo applet that visualizes the algorithms for displaying on a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you do a project that reflects something in the real, physical world.  That will make it easy for your reviewers to understand.

Robotics applications are always fun.  (You don't need a real robot, you can just pretend.)  How about different algorithms to pick the course of a Roomba (robot vacuum cleaner).  If you know where the walls and the furniture are, can you use the algorithms to produce different paths for the robot to clean the room?